# Смежная граница контуров (Adobe Illustrator)

Tags: adobe, вектор, illustrator, svg

С Adobe Illustrator разбирался по ходу дела (вернее не разобрался, потому, собственно, и спрашиваю).

Есть два контура: А и В. Один контур частично перекрывает второй.
[image]

Нужно обрезать контур В по границе контура А, чтобы получить такое:
[image]

---

Сложно будет обьсянить что сделал я сам, т.к. пример абстрактный, но, чесное слово, я не прошу что-то делать за меня)

P.S. Если у кого-то есть больее детальная карта, чем [эта](http://i.webkub.com/world.svg) (Нужна с регионами Англии, Сербии, БЮРМ (Македонии), Словении, Молдовы, стран Прибалтики, Грузии, Армении, Азербайджана, более детальная Венгрии и Греции) - буду признателен.

P.P.S. Все эти карты поодиночке я нашел, беда как-раз в склеивании после "сглаживания" контуров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Они у вас прозрачные или нет? Использовать банальное наложение белого/цветного круга прокатит? Просто передвинуть А перед В?

Но есть меню «обработка контуров» — shift+cmd+F9 (на маке, ща на винде посмотрю).

Было:

[image: Было]

Жмакнули на кнопку (какую вам надо — я так и не понял):

[image: Стало]

2) Использовать яндекс—гугл карты вам поможет? Для чего вам вообще нужна карта?

Comment: Спасибо.То что надо!
Карты нужны для проекта, гугл и яндекс не подходят, иначе я бы не дошел до такого мазохизма :)